# How to apply a text color to everything in an Activity?

Tags: android, widget, styles

I have an Activity, "Eeee", in a tab, declared like this in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity android:name="Eeee"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/eeee"
    />
```

The style is declared like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="eeee">
            <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#ff00ff</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

**Why is it that the text is monospace, as requested, but not purple?**

[image: And this is the result.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add the style to each radioButton attribute.

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/option1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 1" 
    style="@style/eeee"/>
```

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose of having a style. If I'm going to copy/paste a style into every single view, why don't I just copy "android:textColor=#ff00ff"? Accepted nonetheless, because it works.

Comment: I know it was repetitive but I thought maybe the color style may only apply to TextView attributes. If you include a separate TextView after each RadioButton and remove `android:text` from the RadioButton attribute it may pick up the changes.